# Como fazer requisição à uma página em NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, requisição

Gostaria de saber como fazer requisição à uma página usando NodeJS. Basicamente, preciso fazer uma requisição à um webservice que provê dados de lugares baseado no cep informado e a partir da resposta dada (que vem em formato json), tratar os dados e realizar algumas operações. Sou iniciante em node e não sei como fazer isso.
Estou usando o framework express 4.x no projeto.
Agradeço desde já a colaboração de todos!

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que você faz uma requisição a uma página em Apache, IIS, Tomcat... Pela URL.

Comment: Para você que esta começando é bom ver uns tutorial: 
https://code4coders.wordpress.com/2016/10/14/desenvolvendo-uma-aplicacao-restful-api-em-node-js-express-js-com-mongodb/

Vai implementado do simples até chegar no que você quer. Assim que tiver dúvida poste o trecho do seu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ou [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) para fazer requisições em qualquer API de dentro do seu código nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `http` ou `https` do próprio node para fazer a chamada.
Esse exemplo é utilizando as api do mailGun:

```
const https = require('https');

const config = require('./config'); // Meu ficheiro de configuração

helpers.email = function (data, callback) {

    if (data) {
        // Payload
        const payload = {
            'from': config.mailGun.defaultEmail,
            'to': data.email,
            'subject': data.orderId,
            'text': data.body

        };

        var stringPayload = queryString.stringify(data);


        // Request options
        const requestOptions = {
            'protocol': 'https:',
            'hostname': 'api.mailgun.net',
            'path': `/v3/${config.mailGun.sandboxDomain}/messages`,
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`api:${config.mailGun.apiKey}`).toString('base64')}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)

            }
        }
            //making a request
        var req = https.request(requestOptions, res => {
            var status = res.statusCode;
            if (status == 200) {
                callback(status);
                debug(status);
            } else {
                callback(status);
            }
        });
        req.on('data', (data) => {
            callback(data);
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            debug('Email failed to send');
        });
        //attaching the  string payload
        req.write(stringPayload);
        //sending the request
        req.end();

    } else {
        callback('missing required fields');
    }



};
```